# How to run a java file inside of Gatling script?

Tags: java, scala, cucumber, performance-testing, gatling

I am using Gatling for the first time. I have functional tests that are written in java/cucumber. I want to run these functional tests from a Gatling-scala script to do the performance testing of my application. Is there any way to do so?
The idea is to use the existing functional tests and wrap them around gatling scripts so that they could be executed concurrently for multiple users.

Answer (score 2):

What you want to do is to call a Java method from Scala.

Make sure that the method you want to call is available on the class path Scala sees. Then refer to the method you want to call.

This [blog post](https://livebook.manning.com/book/scala-in-action/chapter-11/) may help you.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the Gatling for the first time, have you been considering usage of some other performance tools which can provide you such options? As an analog to Gatling for your case (if you want to create functional tests on Java) and run them later using loading tools  I would recommend you to check the Locust.

Using Locust you can write the tests using Java or even Kotlin. You can find the handy tutorial by this link:

https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/locust-performance-testing-using-java-and-kotlin

Another preferable option might be to use Taurus framework which allows you to run JUnit/TestNG tests right away: 
https://gettaurus.org/docs/JUnit/
https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/navigating-your-first-steps-using-taurus

Answer (score 0):

Gatling is primarily for http testing. what I would do is to call java code from within a gatling test that will return me a value that I check for ex: I return a boolean from a java code below for doing performance test(same also for functional test which needs extending GatlingHttpFunSpec instead of Simulation class). Also will need to use a dummy endpoint (like a health check url which will always return 200).

```
val myJavaTest: MyJavaTest = new MyJavaTest()
val baseURL="http://localhost:8080"
val endpoint_headers=Map("header1" -> "val1")
val endPoint="/myurl/healthcheck"
setUp(scenario("Scenario ")
    .exec(
http("run first test")
        .get(endpoint)
        .headers(endpoint_headers)
        .check(bodyString.transform(str => {
          myJavaTest.runTest1()//should return boolean
    }).is(true)))
.inject(atOnceUsers(1))).protocols(http
  .baseURL(baseURL))
```